# Web app - import from excel file

Tags: java, excel, playframework

I'm a beginner in development and I'm building a simple warehouse management system web application.
I'm using Play framework and I need to figure out how to import from the web app an excel table, match that table with the existing table on the db (that is displayed on the app) and than ask if you want to overwrite fields that are changed, and highlight them once you have done it .
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english...

Luca

Comment: And, you want us to do your job?

Comment: .......  I tend to add as much info as possible to my questions in general, Im just looking for some clues, for what plan to follow, Im certainly not asking you to code for me...

Comment: Hint1: Just ask google first. I tried like "import excel java" https://www.google.ca/search?q=import+excel+java&rls=com.microsoft:en-CA:IE-Address&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7GGNI_enCA652&gfe_rd=cr&ei=mLIKWJ3kFeyM8QeQ0KKIBA&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Hint2: List your problems and solve one by one, one bite at a time is the trick to eat an elephant, Have fun @ Learning.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/modules/excel-1.0.1/home

Comment: OK, I also accept this kind of advices, probably i was trying to go too far with not so much knowledge (euphemism) thanks.

Comment: Come On Luca5om3, everyone is here to learn, don't believe If i say i have knowledge ;-). I am asking google ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check next URL for example use of JExcel (library for Excel read/write) http://www.quicklyjava.com/reading-excel-file-in-java/.